# display in textbox

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to learn how to work with Windows Form Applications in VS and I have found a problem. I am used to console based applications. So the problem is:

I have a form and I want to display a function's result that belongs to another class in a textbox, this I want to do when pressing a button. For example this is a sample class:

```
#ifndef PRUEBA_H
#define PRUEBA_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Prueba
{
public:
    void show() 
    {
       cout<<"Thanks"<<endl;
    }
};

#endif
```

and this is the code for the button:

```
#include "prueba.h"
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

       Prueba *x = new Prueba();
       textBox1->Text= System::Convert::ToString(x->show());
 }
```

The compiler is giving me this error

```
error C2665: 'System::Convert::ToString' : none of the 37 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

Can anyone can please help and post the right way to display a function to a textbox?

Comment: I'm not sure this is still applicable but last time I wrote a C++/CLI app I had to use `gcnew` rather than just `new` if I wanted the object to be garbage collected. You will have to do `Prueba ^x = gcnew Prueba();`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void show() 
{
   cout<<"Thanks"<<endl;
}
```

This function prints some text to standard out, but doesn't return anything.

You need to make it returns a string.

Comment: I went string show(){string text ="thanks"; return text;} and left the code in the form the same, still not working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a string rather than just printing to stdout. Something like --

```
string show() 
{
   return "Thanks";
}
```

Also instead of

```
System::Convert::ToString(x->show());
```

You probably only need

```
x->show();
```

Comment: I did exactly what you posted string show(){return "Thanks";} and still the same error. This is weird, do I need to include something? beside the name of the class in which I have the function? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Nope it complains error C2664: 'void System::Windows::Forms::Control::Text::set(System::String ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'System::String ^'

Comment: Visual Studio is so annoying with the amount of strings that it has I normally solve the problems with System::Convert::To, but never but never printed from a function in a class to a texbox in a form

Comment: One more try
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/e7711471-5b3c-489f-9dad-32b37058a689

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said, you need to have a return type instead of printing into the console.

```
string show() 
{
    return "Thanks";
}
```

But, you also want to remove the convert.

```
textBox1->Text = (x->show());
```

If that still doesn't work, then I suggest you try setting another string the with the function, such as:

```
string v = x->show();
textBox1->Text = v;
```

And see where the compiler is going wrong.

Comment: still nothing. I tried the gcnew instead of new, removing the convert and setting another string with the function and nothing, is going wrong in textBox1->Text = v;

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at `textBox1->Text = v;` and run the code, what does `v` equal? Does it equal "Thanks"? Also, are you getting the same error? Or is it just not displaying?

Comment: it does not get anywhere with the breakpoints it breaks and displays the same error I tried with another function in my class that returns an int and it displayed just fine i did Prueba *x = new Prueba(); int v = System::Convert::ToInt32(x->add(fall, summer)); 
textBox1->Text= Convert::ToString(v);

Comment: Yes, I know it displays an error, but breakpoints are used so you can analyze the values within the code. When it breaks, what is the value of `v`, if you mouse-over it?

Comment: i put the break point i build it and it goes to the error right away it does not gets to the breakpoint I tried putting the breakpoint at Prueba * x = new Prueba(); and it goes right to you have error and it is not letting you see the debugger

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

String^ s
s = marshal_as<String^>( what you want to put in the textbox );
textBox->Text += s + Environment::NewLine;
```